# flutter 'Object' can't be assinged to type 'Widget?' error

Tags: flutter, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm keep getting these error.

I know that the problem is occuring because of Navigator.pushnamed
but I have no Idea how to fix it.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: {
        '/temp': (context) => const Temp(),
        '/menu': (context) => const Menu(),
        '/eat': (context) => const Eat(),
        '/pay': (context) => const Pay(),
        '/main': (context) => const Startpage(),
        '/Veganeat': (context) => const VeganEat(),
        '/Vegancheck': (context) => const VeganChk(),
        '/cheeseeat': (context) => const CheEat(),
        '/cheesecheck': (context) => const CheChk(),
        '/thanks': (context) => const Thanks(),
      },
      home: const Startpage(),
    );
  }
```

```
Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 400,
          child: _speechToText.isListening
              ? _lastWords.contains("vegan burger")
                  ? Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'veganeat')
                  : _lastWords.contains("cheese burger")
                      ? Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'cheeseeat')
                      : Text("tell me which burger to order")
              : Text("loading"))
```

I tried using someother way to move other pages but it didn't work. either

Comment: can you tell me what you're expecting with this block of code, I can help

Comment: I want this to make me move to other page when I spaek some keywords like "vegan burger" or "cheese burger". _lastwords contains what I spoke. so these ? : are checking whether I spoke those keywords or not

Comment: you want to navigate to a new route when you click on some button or what, I mean what kind of interaction you wanna do in order to navigate to that route page

Comment: speech to text is recognizes word as I speak. so when it recognizes sentence that includes "vegan burger" or "cheese burger" I want it to navigate to a new route immediately without any further interaction like pressing button.

Comment: `Container()` widget are expecting a `Widget` but in your ternary operator, you are assigning `Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'veganeat')` as one of the expected result which is not a widget.

Comment: but then how can I navigate to other pages immediately without any further interaction. can I use 'if' to assign Widgets in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get words properly using, https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text
package in here you should get recorgnized words as follows

watch video tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SP9xu5p7rk

After that check the word you want to filter using contains,then navigate it, Add listner properly as follows.

**Other mistake you have done was, you assigning `Navigator.pushNamed(..)` to child of container as one of the expected result which is not a widget.**

you can add "`_onSpeechResult`" listner as in example and then navigate to page from that

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  SpeechToText _speechToText = SpeechToText();
  bool _speechEnabled = false;
  String _lastWords = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initSpeech();
  }

  /// This has to happen only once per app
  void _initSpeech() async {
    _speechEnabled = await _speechToText.initialize();
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// Each time to start a speech recognition session
  void _startListening() async {
    await _speechToText.listen(onResult: _onSpeechResult);
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// Manually stop the active speech recognition session
  /// Note that there are also timeouts that each platform enforces
  /// and the SpeechToText plugin supports setting timeouts on the
  /// listen method.
  void _stopListening() async {
    await _speechToText.stop();
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// This is the callback that the SpeechToText plugin calls when
  /// the platform returns recognized words.
  void _onSpeechResult(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    setState(() {
      _lastWords = result.recognizedWords;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Speech Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Text(
                'Recognized words:',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Text(
                  // If listening is active show the recognized words
                  _speechToText.isListening
                      ? '$_lastWords'
                      // If listening isn't active but could be tell the user
                      // how to start it, otherwise indicate that speech
                      // recognition is not yet ready or not supported on
                      // the target device
                      : _speechEnabled
                          ? 'Tap the microphone to start listening...'
                          : 'Speech not available',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed:
            // If not yet listening for speech start, otherwise stop
            _speechToText.isNotListening ? _startListening : _stopListening,
        tooltip: 'Listen',
        child: Icon(_speechToText.isNotListening ? Icons.mic_off : Icons.mic),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```